# How to retrieve multiple data in a column of a table using a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 **tables named as master and kpi**.
Master table has following columns

> no, name, dtStart, dtEnd, status, user and dtCreate

kpi table has following columns

> no and kpName

**"no" in kpi table refers "no" in master table**

What i expect to do is, when I select a name from the dropdownlist relevant details in both tables should be displayed.
One **name has unique "no".** Also **"no" can have multiple kpNames.**
Please help me.

Comment: Please tell us the relationship between these two tables, ideally along with some sample data.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: Lookup `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT a.[no], a.name, a.dtStart, a.dtEnd, a.[status], a.[user] , a.dtCreate 
From masterTable  a 
Inner JOIN kpiTable b ON a.[no] = b.[no]
Where b.Name = 'dropDownSelectedValueName'
```

Comment: as mentioned, u can create a stored Procedure and call it on every time drop down selection change, it has its own advantages.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a stored procedure and then join both tables. Here is sample

```
create proc Details
begin
@Name char(50)
select * from Master m join kpi n ON
 m.no==n.no where Name== @Name
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table1.[no], table1.name, table1.dtStart, table1.dtEnd, 
table1.[status], table1.[user] , table1.dtCreate ,table2.kpName 
FROM masterTable [table1] 
INNER JOIN kpiTable [table2] 
ON table1.[no] = table2.[no] 
WHERE table2.Name = 'Your Selected value'
```